# Cannot implicitly convert type of IEnumerable<T> to IEnumerable<T>

Tags: c#, generics

Consider the following code:

```
namespace TestNameSpace {
  public interface IFinder
  {
    IEnumerable<T> GetData<T>(DataStore dataStore);
  }

  public class EmployeeFinder : IFinder {
    public IEnumerable<Employee> GetData<Employee>(DataStore dataStore) {
        return dataStore.Employees; //*****This causes an error*****
    }
  }

  public class DataStore {
    public IEnumerable<Employee> Employees { get; set;}
  }

  public class Employee {

  }
}
```

The line where I return dataStore.Employees causes a compilation error.

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TestNameSpace.Employee>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Employee>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Why is an implicit conversion required when they are the same type? Why is one namespaced while the other isn't?

Thanks!

Comment: You have two different types of the same name (`Employee`) in different namespaces. Look through your codebase for missing namespace declarations or accidentally redefined classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have used `Employee` as name for method generic parameter, so you have two different meaning for `Employee` in your code.

```
namespace TestNameSpace {
  public interface IFinder
  {
    IEnumerable<T> GetData<T>(DataStore dataStore);
  }

  public class EmployeeFinder : IFinder {
    public IEnumerable<EmployeeGenericParameter> GetData<EmployeeGenericParameter>(DataStore dataStore) {
        return dataStore.Employees;
    }
  }

  public class DataStore {
    public IEnumerable<EmployeeClass> Employees { get; set;}
  }

  public class EmployeeClass {

  }
}
```

And `IEnumerable<EmployeeClass>` can not be converted to `IEnumerable<EmployeeGenericParameter>` as `EmployeeGenericParameter` can be `int` or whatever else.

Comment: Ah, I see what I did wrong. So is the only way around this to cast the return? I was hoping to avoid a cast.  public IEnumerable<T> GetData<T>(DataStore dataStore) {
        return (IEnumerable<T>)dataStore.Employees; 
    }

Comment: @rkrauter Yes you should use explicit cast, as it can fail in runtime. Compiler does not take that responsibility by silently inserting may-to-fail cast, you should take that responsibility explicitly.

Answer (score 2):

You have created two distinct definitions of the type `Employee`. One as a plain class and the other as the generic parameter to your `GetData` method.

This is easily fixed. Just move the generic parameter from the `GetData` method to the `IFinder` interface itself. Here's how you should have defined your interface:

```
public interface IFinder<T>
{
    IEnumerable<T> GetData(DataStore dataStore);
}
```

Now `EmployeeFinder` works if it's implemented like this:

```
public class EmployeeFinder : IFinder<Employee>
{
    public IEnumerable<Employee> GetData(DataStore dataStore)
    {
        return dataStore.Employees;
    }
}
```